# Center text on bottom of the div container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Could someone explain me how do I center my text on bottom of the div container?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <header id="welcome-header" class="row">
            <div id="welcome-div">
                <a href="#" class="home-logo"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
                <h1 class="welcome-text">
                    <span>Hi, I'm Robert. I design & build</span>
                    <br>
                    <span class="welcome-text-animation"></span>
                </h1>
                <div class="hire-button">
                    <a href="footer">Yes, I'm available for hire</a>
                </div>
                <div class="page-scroll ">
                    <a href="#welcome-div">
                        Learn more about what i do
                        <br>
                        <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>        
        </header>
```

Im trying to get "Learn more about what i do" at the bottom of "welcome-header" row.

CSS :

```
#welcome-div {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.page-scroll {   

}

.page-scroll a {
    font-family: Sansita; 
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: aliceblue;
}
```

Sorry guys u get me wrong. I want the string to stick to bottom like bottom: 0px;

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jBLaBX

Comment: looks to me like "learn more about what I do" is at the bottom of #welcome-header? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PpKObE

Comment: @look edit please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `position: relative` to `#welcome-header` then `position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0` to `.page-scroll` to position the element at the bottom of `#welcome-header`, and your `text-align: center` rule will center the text horizontally.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sansita');
#welcome-header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(img/background.jpg);
  position: relative;
}

.welcome-text,
.welcome-text-animation {
  font-family: Sansita;
  text-align: center;
  color: aliceblue;
  font-size: 50px;
  padding-top: 90px;
}

.home-logo {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.home-logo img {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2.5%;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
}

.hire-button {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 90px;
}

.hire-button a {
  font-family: Sansita;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: aliceblue;
  font-size: 25px;
  border: 2px solid #FDCD3B;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding: 1.2%;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.hire-button a:hover {
  background-color: #FDCD3B;
  color: #2A3A3F;
  padding-left: 3%;
  padding-right: 3%;
}

#welcome-div {}

.page-scroll {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.page-scroll a {
  font-family: Sansita;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <header id="welcome-header" class="row">
      <div id="welcome-div">
        <a href="#" class="home-logo"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
        <h1 class="welcome-text">
                    <span>Hi, I'm Robert. I design & build</span>
                    <br>
                    <span class="welcome-text-animation"></span>
                </h1>
        <div class="hire-button">
          <a href="footer">Yes, I'm available for hire</a>
        </div>
        <div class="page-scroll ">
          <a href="#welcome-div">
                        Learn more about what i do
                        <br>
                        <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
                    </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>

    <section id="about" class="row">
      ABOUT CONTENT
    </section>

    <section id="skills" class="row">
      SKILLS CONTENT
    </section>

    <section id="portfolio" class="row">
      PORTFOLIO CONTENT
    </section>

    <section id="contact" class="row">
      CONTACT CONTENT HERE
    </section>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Awesome ! Thanks !

Comment: @robertbie np :)

Answer (score 0):

```
.page-scroll {  
   text-align:center;  
 }
```

Comment: I mean, the text have to be at the bottom and middle at the same time .

Comment: @robertbie its already the last element in that container element. It's at the bottom already?

Comment: @robertbie ah ok that makes more sense - so almost like a sticky footer? That is always at the bottom of the screen at the user scrolls? Or just right at the bottom of the page?

Comment: Right at the bottom of the page. Im not talking about sticky (fixed) div here :)

Comment: Please explain your code short answers like this are discouraged on SO.